# How odefun works (matlab)

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I'm trying to figure out how to solve differential equations in matlab

> [t,y] = ode45(odefun,tspan,y0).

And I hava an example of **odefun**, but i'm not sure what part of this code does or i just don't understand syntax. **eq(1,1)=, eq(2,1)=, eq(3,1)**= - are vectors? Is first argument time? and the second argument is responsible for what? Any help is appreciated!

```
function eq = f (t, y)


t0=0.2;
x=y(1)+t0*y(2);

P = 11 - (t + y(3));
if (11 - (t + y(3))<=0) 
  P = -1;
end

eq(1,1)=y(2);
eq(2,1)=-P*sign(x);
eq(3,1)=0;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`eq` is expected to be a column vector, here of the format 3x1. The assignments in question are for its components. You could also have written

```
eq =  [ y(2); -P*sign(x); 0 ]
```

which means that the component `y(3)` is constant and `y(2)` is the derivative of `y(1)`.

Usually this is the setup for a boundary value problem with one variable parameter.